# Output from C# to html web page - UTF8 fails?

Tags: c#, html, utf-8

Hey,
so we have a backend written in C# and we have text in that backend in a language which has "special characters".

Problem is when I output my saved text (from C# app) to the web page (ASP.NET), the characters are all messed up even though the browser interprest the page as UTF (since I have placed a meta tag telling the browser that it is UTF8).

But since its all messed up, Im sort of questioning what the output from C# is. Its probably not UTF8, but something else. Somewhere I read that text in .NET is usually UTF-16?

Basically, I am assigning a label (that can do HTML) with a value taken from the backend. That needs to be in UTF8.

How do I do that in the best way?

Comment: I don't think you've sufficiently described the issue. How is the text stored in your text file? How are you outputting it to the web page? What does "messed up" mean?

Comment: The text is stored in a C# object, and that is stored in database. its a "string", nothing more.

Comment: Its output:ed in ASP.NET (using ext.net) in code-behind like: lblMyGreatLabel.Html = SRef.GetText("TheTExt);
and the GetText returns "string"

Answer (score 4):

.NET strings are natively encoded as UTF-16. The following will set the HTTP output to UTF-8:

```
Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
```

Answer (score 0):

Better resources:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/39d1w2xf.aspx

[`Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(xxx);`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.contentencoding%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: As I said in the post, that is already done: "since I have placed a meta tag telling the browser that it is UTF8"

Comment: Well, get some proof and post a public page somewhere so we can see what the problem is. There must be something about the way in which you are telling the browser, that the browser isn't fully understanding :)

Answer (score 0):

When outputting special characters in HTML, you should escape them anyways using Unicode escape sequences (for example `&#233;` makes `é`).

Comment: Well, in this case ppl are going to manually edit that text... And they are using keyboards that has these special characters. They cannot, in the editor, write &#233. They'll write like õ and stuff...

Comment: Yes, but with C# it's easy to escape things like that in code. Come to think of it though, I'm not sure if ASP.NET Label controls escape ampersands already and I can't test it, so don't bother. You could try outputting a Content-Type header instead of a `<meta>` tag though.